# TabControl fixed tab positions

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

Hello I am making a WPF appication which has an ObservableCollection that is bound to a TabControl (each tab representing an object within OC). And at the end there is a "+" tab, that adds a new object to that collection. My question is, is it possible to fix the tabs position, so they don't jump when i click on a tab in a different row, because i want the "+" tab to be always on the last position. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upon clicking `+` tab to add new object to your `ObservableCollection`, try to add it at specific position using [Insert()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132411%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function. For example, to make the new item added at position before the last item in collection :

```
MyCollection.Insert(MyCollection.Count-1, newItem);
```